# html / php - image clean up with HTML parsing or regular expression?

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-parsing

I'm trying to clean some legacy content in my CMS to unify the way tags are being used, I wanted to start with images but I bumped into some problems.

The content in image tags like alt, srcset, sizes,... is not always used and when it is used, it is not always used in the same order. I tried two different angles to clean up my code:

1. HTML parsing

I have tried PHP simple html dom and the alternative through PHP with the following code: (it's just an example, I don't want class to be set to "blabla")

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) 
  {
    $image->setAttribute('class', 'blabla');
  }
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

When I do this, image classes are correctly adapted but many DIVs in $html have vanished while I haven't modified them. I originally had something like this:

```
<section id="mysection">
<div class="mydiv">test</div>
<section>
```

and I end up with this:

```
<section id="mysection">
test
<section>
```

As this first method was actually worsening my problem, I tried to work with REGEX.

2. REGEX

I went the easy way by using the following pattern: `/<img(.*)>/` and then I would explode the result to identify all the tags inside img. The issue I got here is that the REGEX ignored the ending `>` of the expression and end up taking a lot of unwanted html code. It should stop at the first occurence of a `>` but I don't know how to do this.

I suppose html parsing should be the preferred method for this kind of operation but the parsing destroys my code.

Do you have any idea of which method I should use to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a `?` so the `*` is not greedy... or you can use the `U` modifier so it functions opposite. You should use the parser though. (Also note you aren't using `PHP simple html dom` you are using `domdocument`.)

Comment: Can you please post a full example? That example has no `img`. It appears to work for me,  https://3v4l.org/OeHZL (your closing `section` is missing a `/` in the example)